# In C#, what is the best way to read in a text file with thiis format and convert to list of objects?

Tags: c#, parsing, collections

I am reading in a text file of bank transactions and the file is in a specific format to parse.  I ultimately want to read in this file and convert the data into a list of BankTransactions objects where this is the definition of a bankTransaction:

```
public class BankTransaction
{
     public DateTime Date;
     public string Description;
     public Decimal Amount;
     public string Category;
}
```

The tricky part is that the text file data is grouped by category and then it lists out all of the transactions.  So for example, the contents of a file might look like this

```
Food
Date
Description
Amount
1/1/2018
First Purchase
10.00
1/2/2018
Second Purchase
12.00
Homegoods
Date
Description
Amount
1/3/2018
First Purchase
144.00
1/5/2018
Second Purchase
1444.00
```

so the template is

The first line is Category name
The next 3 lines are headings (Date, Description, Amount)
The next 3 lines are all attributes of the first transaction  and then that repeats for all of the transactions in that category .

Once all of the transactions are complete for that category, the next line is the next category name.

When I read in the textfile, i just get an array of string (one for each line).

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Bank\transactions.txt");
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to take this array of lines and convert into the structure above so I can then convert into this array of banktransaction objects?

Comment: why close votes?

Comment: If I were to parse that file, I would create a Class That mimics the data structure, star reading all lines into a List<T> and withing a While Loop get all the values using substring function.. this is actually not that difficult to do.. however with an `27.9k` reputation, one would think that you would show a little bit more than you have posted..

Comment: Do you have somewhere a finite list of the possible categories?

Comment: @Steve  - no category is just a string

Comment: Why don't you read line by line and figure out the processing from there instead of reading the entire text file into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the presence of the category name before the headers and data. This creates a condition to consider while looping over the lines because when we read a category name we need to consider 4 rows while when reading the transaction data we have to loop over 3 rows.

However there is a pattern in the data that we could exploit with a normal loop. If every 3 rows we can convert the line to a datetime then we could procede to create a BankTransaction with the other two lines, otherwise we could read the category name and skip the next 3 lines.

```
List<BankTransaction> result = new List<BankTransaction>();
string currentCat = string.Empty;

for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x += 3)
{
    DateTime dt;
    string line = lines[x];

    // If we can convert the line to a date, we are to the beginning
    // of a BankTransaction for the current category
    if (DateTime.TryParse(line, out dt))
    {
        // We never enter this if on the first line 
        // according to your sample text.
        BankTransaction bt = new BankTransaction()
        {
            Date = dt,
            Description = lines[x+1],
            Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(lines[x+2]),
            Category = currentCat
        };
        result.Add(bt);
    }
    else
    {
        // We are on the category line, get the name and add 
        // 1 more line to the 3 skipped in the loop
        currentCat = line;
        x++;
    }
}
```